# Defining target & train values for LSTM model

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have multiple dataframes (5 to 6) which look like this:

```
>dataframe1
  time(min)  A   B  C  D
0  0         1   2  3  4
1  1         ...........
2  2         ...........
```

I am trying to do an LSTM 5 min in the future for all those data frames having target as their columns (A & B). How could I make my X_test and X_train taking all those data from all of the data frame alltogether? Also how could I probably get their shifting ?
While I was trying to make test data and train data, I tried this: I made a 3D data frame look like this:

```
   dataframe 1       dataframe 2      dataframe 3
time   A  B  C  D        A  B  C D        A  B  C  D
0
1
2
```

I am trying this code for target value defining

```
target_dataframe=['dataframe1','dataframe2', 'dataframe3']
target_column=['A','B']
df_targets = df[target_dataframe][target_dataframe].shift(-shift_steps)
```

I am finding this error after this

```
"['A','B'] "not in index"
```

However , if I define only one dataframe for predicition it doesnt show the error

```
target_dataframe=['dataframe1']
```

But I want my model to work for all dataframes at once

I am really confused here as I can't make the time shift to do the prediction properly.Can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you please specify what shoud be your input timestep i.e how many timesteps you want to look to predict next 5 timestep. From the question it's clear he output step is 5. Also does C & D column represent features here?

Comment: @dufrmbgr Thanks. I wanted to look back to 14 or 15 timestep to predict the next 5. I have edited how my 3d dataframe looks like. I am also gettimg trouble to select desired shape of my dataframe for target selection.

Answer (score 1):

First, lets generate some data. (100 Datapoints). Assume we are looking at 15 data points to predict next 5.

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 4), columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"])
df["time"] = np.arange(100)
```

Shift 15 target data points since we don't want to look at their "A" and "B" columns rather we should look at next 5.

```
df["A_shifted"] = df["A"].shift(-15)
df["B_shifted"] = df["B"].shift(-15)
```

A_shifted and B_shifted are the target columns

```
#Note - There are probably better ways to do this but for pedagogic purpose 
X = []
y = []
for i in range(len(df) - 15):
    X.append(df[["C", "D"]].iloc[i:i+15].values) #our features are C & D
    y.append(df[["A_shifted", "B_shifted"]].iloc[i:i+5].values) #target value next 5
X, y = np.array(X), np.array(y)

print(X.shape, y.shape)
#(85, 15, 2) (85, 5, 2)
```

Note the shape of X and y. X has 85 data points, each has a shape of (15, 2). 15 here represents the time steps we are looking to predict next 5 steps. 2 represent 2 features in our example (columns "C" and "D").

Similarly from the shape of y, 85 is the number of data points, 5 is the output sequence length. 2 is the number of target variable "A" and "B".

The shape of X and y outputted here are generally what's required by most of the deep learning framework such as pytorch, keras etc.

Note: Because of shifting you might see some `nan` values in target which you probably have to remove.